# Website sync of contacts and reminders with iCloud

Tags: php, python, api, synchronization, icloud

I'm building custom CRM web based system and have integrated synchronization of contacts and reminders with Google apps and need do the same with Apple iCloud. Is there any way how to do it? I haven't find any official API for this purpose, CRM is written in PHP, but I'm able to use python for this purpose as well.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to interface with iCloud directly; it can only be done through an iOS or Mac OS app, and by calling the correct iCloud Objective-C APIs with UI/NSDocument classes. Since you are not using Cocoa, let alone Objective-C, you will most likely not be able to do this. I may be wrong of course, as I haven't conducted an in-depth search into this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you sync using the google contacts api.  Then, you can tell iPhone people to use that instead of iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first and second answer since I too haven't found any solution to access a large portion of the iCloud data via PHP. It seems the best solution would be to make an mobile app to do most of the work. This may save a lot of time in fact.

However if you can get your users to install an app then make your own cloud. There is an open source software like:  own Cloud link below that is very good at it.

https://owncloud.org/

Answer (score -1):

You may want to take a look at this project: https://github.com/adammck/ruby-icloud . It accesses iCloud reminders using Ruby.